# Conditional if selecting by pattern

Tags: r

Let's say I have a data like this:

```
data <- as.list(c("Cb-a.csv", "Cc-a.csv", "Cd-a.csv", "Ca-e.csv"))
```

where C is a constant part and the letter in the real case is a pattern of letter and 2 numbers. I would like to do different things depending on which

Like:

```
for (n in 1:length(data)){
 if ( data[[n]] == <condition> ){
  cat("Do this with 'Cb-a.csv', 'Cc-a.csv', 'Cd-a.csv'\n")}
  else{
   cat("Do this with 'Ca-e.csv'\n")}
}
```

Which should be my `<condition>` ? 
It must distinguish the order or the pattern of the data input. (Reading differences between 'Ca-e.csv' and 'Ce-a.csv' ).

In some way it must recreate the data but with a "correct pattern" to see if it fits. (But not manually)

At first I thought about a grep condition, but in this case I would just get which pattern is in data.

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you want to do. Are these files that you would load, or values in a data frame (or column)? `grep` is a way to generate your `if` condition, but if you are going pull out all values and plot them, then `subset` or `which` or indexing `df[data=='Ca-e.csv']` might be more efficient.

Comment: `sapply(data, function(x) grepl(pattern="b-a|c-a|d-a", x=x))` will extract anything which matches what might be your group of "correct" patterns. Use that to subset and do whatever, or use it in an `ifelse` statement.

Comment: I do not want to load the files, they are values that I created as I showed. In fact they aren't even objects.
@AnandaMahto good idea, I thought about subset, but I prefer not to create more objects. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grepl` returns a boolean vector.

```
if ( grepl("^C.-a.csv$", data[[n]]) ) {
  cat("Do this\n")
} else {
  cat("Do that\n")
}
```

The exact regular expression depends on the real pattern you want to match.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! It works better with a one more bracket and a \n after this and that ;)